# Calculate the $ \lim_{r \to 1} {r(\sqrt{n-2}) /(\sqrt{1-r^2})}$, for every $n \in \mathbb{N} $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Calculate the following limit:
$\lim\limits_{r \to 1} {r(\sqrt{n-2}) /(\sqrt{1-r^2})}$, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Thoughts: I think that the limit is equal to infinity because the denominator is equal to zero. But $ (\sqrt{n-2})$ is not always positive, it can also be equal to zero or not exist, so I don't know.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{r\to 1}{r \cdot \frac{n-\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}}.$

For $r\to 1, \sqrt{1-r^2} \to 0$. So $\lim_{r\to 1}{r \cdot \frac{n-\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}} = \pm\infty $.

If it is positive or negative infinity depends on $n$.
If $n < 2$, then it's negative infinity as the sum at the nominator becomes negative. If $n \geq 2$ then it's positive infinity as the sum at the nominator becomes positive.

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake, its not $(n- \sqrt{2})$, but $(\sqrt{n-2})$

Comment: Ok then for $n \geq 2$ the limit is still positive infinity. For $n = 2$ the function is always $0$ where it is defined $(-1,1)$.

Comment: in the first expression of my last comment i meant to say $n > 2$